# How to send JSON object to a component in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am new to React and am running through a tutorial that uses the Poke API (https://pokeapi.co).

I am using whatwg-fetch to make requests to the API. This saves data from the API as an object to the state 'selectedPokemon'.

```
    this.state = {
      // other states
      showModal: false,
      selectedPokemon: null
    };
```

I want to send that data to a component (in my case a modal), so I updated my modal component call to include the selectedPokemon state as a prop:

```
<PokemonModal pokemon={this.state.selectedPokemon} closeModal={this.handleModalClose} showModal={this.state.showModal} />
```

I also updated my PokemonModal component (on PokemonModal.js) to include `pokemon` as a prop:

```
const PokemonModal = ({showModal, closeModal, pokemon}) => {
```

However, when I go to use that prop within `PokemonModal`, eg:

```
<Modal.Title>{pokemon.name}</Modal.Title>
```

I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

(This is the same with any other part of the object I try to use eg `pokemon.order`. The showModal and closeModal props work as expected.)

Would anyone know how I could send and use a JSON object to another component?

---

If it matters, my fetch function is set up as such. The console.log returns the expected result, which is the object from: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/10125/

```
  handleModalOpen(pokemon) {
    if(pokemon.url !== undefined) {
      fetch(`${pokemon.url}`)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
          this.setState({
            selectedPokemon: json,
            showModal: true
          }) 
          console.log('selected: ' + this.state.selectedPokemon);
        })
        .catch(ex => {
          console.log('pasrsing failed ' + ex);
        })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectedPokemon` would be `undefined` untill the request to `pokemon.url` finishes.

And thus, Initially the `<PokemonModal .../>` will receive `pokemon` as `undefined`. Because of which, you are seeing the error.

One way to solve it would be to have an `if` in the `PokemonModal` component:

```
const PokemonModal = ({showModal, closeModal, pokemon}) => {
    if(pokemon && Object.keys(pokemon).length !== 0) {
        // prepare the view and return it
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

You can also have an `if` on your parent component too, But generally speaking, I like to have the `if` in child component so that the parent component would not get cluttered by so many `if`s

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get a `TypeError`, is because you initialize your state with `null`, and while waiting to the response the modal tried to read the name property of pokemon.
you need to handle the case when there is no pokemon set yet inside the modal,
when rendering you can add 

`` const PokemonModal = ({showModal, closeModal, pokemon}) => {
    if (!pokemon) {return "Loading..."}`
} ``

or some loading spinner.

no need to use JSON in here imho

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async, that's why your component is failing, as you are opening the modal, but the state might not have been set and propagated to the children yet.
one way to solve this is to add a loading state to your modal.

```js
return (
pokemon&&{
    <Modal>
      <Modal.Title>{pokemon.name}</Modal.Title>
    </Modal>
}

)
```